# Existence of a differentiable bijection between manifolds with non-differentiable inverse

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology, manifolds

In my abstract algebra/topology course, my teacher has touched on a question that left me puzzled.

> Does there exist a differentiable bijection $f:M \to N$ between differentiable manifolds $M$ and $N$ such that the inverse $f^{-1}:N \to M$ is NOT differentiable?

I think it should be possible to find such an example with $M=N=\mathbb{R}$, but I can't think of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f(x)=x^3$ is such a bijection.